# React JS how to change the state without refresh page

Tags: reactjs

How to change the state (dataNotification) when the dropdown item closed without refresh the page?

[image]

```
 <CNavLink href="#">
      <CIcon name="cil-bell" size="lg" onClick={openNotification} />
      {dataNotification !== 0 ? <div className="topIconBadgeNotification" onClick={openNotification}>{dataNotification}</div>
        :
        <div className="topIconBadgeNotification" onClick={openNotification}>0</div>
      }
    </CNavLink>
  </CNavItem>
</CDropdownToggle>
{dataNotification !== 0 ? <CDropdownMenu>
  <div>
    {ref.map(function (el, index) {
      return (
        <>
          <CDropdownItem href="#" key={index} className="label-notif">
            {el.commande_ref}

          </CDropdownItem>
        </>
      )
    })}
  </div>
</CDropdownMenu> : ''}
```

Comment: `useEffect` hook

Comment: in the useEffect  i get the number of the notifications, and i create a function openNotification() to get the content of the notification, but now i wanna when i close the <CDropdownMenu> the dataNotification changed to 0 wihtout refreshing page and the same time gide the <CDropdownMenu> (not opend)